# Show standard Android app chooser while file is being downloaded

Tags: android, android-intent

Application uses Android app chooser to share an image:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageToShareUri);
sendIntent.setType("image/png");
String titleForChooser = getString(R.string.app_chooser_title);
Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, titleForChooser)

startActivityForResult(sendIntent, APPS_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE);
```

The flow is the following:

1. User selects an item
2. App downloads and prepares a high definition image
3. App creates standard Android chooser and calls `startActivityForResult()`
4. User looks through a list of apps in the Android app chooser and selects one
5. Image is shared to a selected app

Is it possible to show an app chooser while an image is still being prepared:

- Once both the image is ready, and the app has been chosen, share the image with the app.
- If the image preparation task is completed before the app is chosen, wait until the app is chosen (or cancelled).

So is it possible to have the 2nd step done in parallele with 3rd and 4th? Thanks.

Comment: No. This is not possible. Unless you make your own 'app chooser'.